# Terraform retrieve the latest GCE image by name and timestamp

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, google-compute-engine, gcloud

I have multiple images on Google Cloud with this format:

```
test-${creationTimestamp}
```

I could easily retrieve the latest image by using gcloud:

```
gcloud compute images list --filter=name=test --limit=1 --sort-by=~creationTimestamp
```

[The problem is that Terraform doesn't let me use `limit` or `sort-by`.](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/data-sources/compute_image)

This is the max I can do:

```
data "google_compute_image" "my_image" {
  filter = "(name=test)"
}
```

And it will return more than one which means it won't work:

```
Error: your filter has returned more than one image or no image. Please refine your filter to return exactly one image
```

Any idea on how can I achieve this without using gcloud?

Comment: Is there a reason you can't create your images with a `family` and then use that to select the latest in the family?

Comment: I misunderstood source_image_family with image_name, I didn't know I could give a custom name to the image family, that means what you suggested did work. Thank you! @ydaetskcoR (You can create an answer and I will accept it if you want)